# as3 how to catch focus selection event?

Tags: actionscript-3, tabs, navigation, focus, accessibility

Is it possible to catch a "Focus selection" on a movieclip (using accessibility stuff such as TAB, ARROWS, ENTER and SPACE keys only)?

In the following example, I can't find a way to catch the "Focus selection" on the blue square. Any suggestions?

```
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.FocusEvent;

// build red button
var btSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
btSprite.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
btSprite.graphics.drawRect(0,0,20,20);
btSprite.graphics.endFill();
var redBtn:SimpleButton;
redBtn = new SimpleButton(btSprite, btSprite, btSprite, btSprite);
addChild(redBtn);
redBtn.x = redBtn.y = 0;

// build blue square
var blueSquare:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
blueSquare.graphics.beginFill(0x0000ff);
blueSquare.graphics.drawRect(0,0,20,20);
blueSquare.graphics.endFill();
addChild(blueSquare);
blueSquare.x = blueSquare.y = 100; // not sure it does not show over myBtn

// set blue square selectable using TAB key
blueSquare.tabEnabled = true;
blueSquare.focusRect = true;

// listen events
redBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onEvent);         // work click / tab select
blueSquare.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onEvent);         // does not work
blueSquare.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onEvent);     // works click only

// catch events on objects
function onEvent(event:Event){
    trace((event.target?event.target.name:'none') + " selected!");
}
```

Comment: check if "blueSquare.mouseEnabled" is true, try setting it and check your conditions again.

Comment: need more coffee, totally saw a shape declaration that wasn't there...

Comment: Have you tried using the focus event?

Comment: Well Focus events allow me to catch focus in/out only. There is no FocusEvent.SELECT. What i'm looking for is to catch when user select it (using space bar or enter)

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question,  as when most people say focus select they mean the focus changing from object to another.  There is no space bar or enter triggered select event. you'll have to use a key listener

Comment: No problems. I'm afraid I will need to listen focus and keyboard events to catch it...

Comment: Did you find a solution, if so please either accept an answer, or answer it yourself (and accept)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the focus events?

```
FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN
```

here is a good tutorial:
http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?311824-AS3-Simple-focus-example

In regards to arrow keys or space bar or enter, you'll need to use a key Listener:

```
blueSquare.addEventListner(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);

function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    switch(event.keyCode){
        case Keyboard.SPACE:
        case Keyboard.ENTER:
            //do your select
            break;

        case Keyboard.DOWN:
            //do what you want when the down arrow is pressed
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need to catch the selection, not the focus. Focus alreay works in this example since "tabEnabled" is set to true.

Comment: you'll need to use a key listener then. I updated the answer.  The keyDownHandler will only run if blueSquare has focus.